# grid fill columns of element width to 150% of page width

Tags: css

Pointless but required details:
I could build the software myself as its open source but its server software so i don,t want to
This relates to a self made CSS theme, tho there might be a alternate solution i don't want it
I am open to other solutions that acomplish the same thing and is pure css and is in the same ish scope, unlikely tho they may be.

Actual problem:
create a grid filled with columns of element width spanning 150% of screen or document width

Important info:
I DO NOT have access to the JS or HTML
Element size is determined by code that i don't have access to
Each element is the same size WITCH I DO NOT HAVE see above
I DO want it to overflow to the right of the page that's kinda the point

```
.homePage .itemsContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(calc(100vw/max-content),1fr); /* this is the relevant line */
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
  }
```

Attempted:
flex: 1 dimensional it simply wont do
grid: auto minmax calc min-content max-content fill-content fit-content fr vw % none of witch worked
obviously tried several sources for a solution but no dice.

calc could in theory work, unfortunately it wont work with min/max-content

new info:
parent is a emby-scroller
itemContainer is a emby-itemContainer
The program in question is jellyfin
when set to `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,auto);` a single column is created covering the entire thing. `repeat(auto-fill,min-width);`
same result, probly since `min-width:150%;` to ensure container size

current closest to solution:

```
.homePage .emby-scroller {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
.homePage .itemsContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,20em);
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    min-width:150%;
  }
```

issues:
item container always 150% even with no items
different containers with different objects are all the same size, in this case 20em aka 20*font is used witch means font is same size and unrelated to object.

Comment: maybe `grid-template-columns: repeat(6,25vw);`  ? so it does 150% of screen's width. Un less i totally did not understand your issue.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus 6 is just filler i do not in fact want 6 entries i want as many entries as can fit in 150% of the screen width  
edited that part to avoid further confusion

Comment: oki, then `.homePage .itemsContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,auto);
    min-width:150%;
  }` might be good enough to stretch the container to 150%'s width of its parent ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus 
Progress for sure.  
if there arent enugh elements to fill the container is still 150 width, that is not necesarribly a deal breaker but wuld ne nice to avoid
it also seems like auto-fill is not working, perhaps the grid is being fed objects, in any case this is important.
each container has differetn objects,
the object in a container are all same size

info: the parent element is a emby-scroller
the itemcontainer isa emby-itemcontainer

note: flexboxes have correct size on auto, but are unfortunatly not 2 dimensional, and thats thats why i opped for grid.

Comment: hello, i'm afraid that some javascript will be needed to reset your column's width and container's width . css can see :empty elements, but then is unable to apply min or max-content's width to a repeating grid. :( If elements are added on the fly via a server script or js, this probably where you'll be able to handle width and columns pattern.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus
i kinda suspected as mutch, my css knowledge just waren't strong enough to confirm by my self. strange that everything lined up with flex boxes, but i suppose threes some js in the back handling the layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
.homePage .itemsContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(idealsizehere, 1fr) );
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
  }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width to `150%` then put whatever you want in there.

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 150%;
  outline: 2px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```